# How do I get a scalar value from a stored proc using Nettiers

Tags: .net, t-sql, stored-procedures, .nettiers

I have a really simple stored procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _Visitor_GetVisitorIDByVisitorGUID
(
 @VisitorGUID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

AS

DECLARE @VisitorID AS bigint

SELECT @VisitorID = VisitorID FROM dbo.Visitor WHERE VisitorGUID = @VisitorGUID

--Here's what I've tried 
RETURN @VisitorID 'Returns an IDataReader
SELECT @VisitorID 'Returns an IDataReader
--I've also set it up with a single output
--parameter, but that means I need to pass
--the long in by ref and that's hideous to me
```

I'm trying to get nettiers to generate a method with this signature:

```
public long VisitorService.GetVisitorIDByVisitorGUID(GUID visitorGUID);
```

Basically I want Nettiers to call ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Nettiers, but FWIW, you have to return a resultset, not set the RETURN value when using ExecuteScalar - so your "SELECT @VisitorID" approach would be right. But I don't know about the Nettiers side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the custom data access functionality to call your stored proc with ExecuteScalar? (http://nettiers.com/DataLayer.ashx#Read_Methods:_4)

```
var vistorId = (long)DataRepository.Provider.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "_Visitor_GetVisitorIDByVisitorGUID");
```

The body of the stored proc should look like:

```
Select VisitorID 
FROM dbo.Visitor 
WHERE VisitorGUID = @VisitorGUID

Return
```

or

```
Declare @VisitorId bigint
Set @VisitorId = (
                Select VisitorId
                From dbo.Visitor
                Where VisitorGuid = @VisitorGUID
                )

Select @VisitorId

Return
```

Comment: That helps, but I still think I should be able to use the the service layer (we have caching setup) without having to create a custom method.

Comment: @Micah - Given the way the docs read, I'm guessing that anytime you go off the reservation of wanting something other than an entire instance (i.e. a whole row), you have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to do this programatically, the above example will not work as there is no way to pass the necessary parameter value using any of that method's overrides.

```
var vistorId = (long)DataRepository.Provider.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "_Visitor_GetVisitorIDByVisitorGUID");
```

The only way I've found to accomplish this is by passing a DbCommand as a lone argument to the ExecuteScalar method:

```
int myReturnID = 0;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_MyStoredProcedure";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MyParameter", myParameter));
    myReturnID = (Int32)DataRepository.Provider.ExecuteScalar(cmd);
}
```